# How to set EKS server for kubectl to talk to?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, eksctl

I'm new to Kubernetes and was following some examples for setting contexts. Now I can't seem to get any objects on my server, or I'm talking to the wrong server. I see...

```
$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: ""
  name: sandbox
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://redacted.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: sandbox.us-east-1.eksctl.io
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: sandbox.us-east-1.eksctl.io
    user: me@company.com@sandbox.us-east-1.eksctl.io
  name: me@company.com@sandbox.us-east-1.eksctl.io
- context:
    cluster: sandbox
    namespace: kube-system
    user: ""
  name: sandbox
current-context: sandbox
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: me@company.com@sandbox.us-east-1.eksctl.io
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - sandbox
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env:
      - name: AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS
        value: regional
      - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        value: us-east-1
```

I see the cluster in AWS EKS, and see pods, deployments, etc. But when I do the following

```
$ kubectl get pods -A
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "pods"
$ kubectl get nodes -A
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "nodes"
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current context is `sandbox`, try changing the current-context with [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) or directly in `~/.kube/config`.

```sh
$ kubectl config get-contexts
$ kubectl config use-context me@company.com@sandbox.us-east-1.eksctl.io
```

Comment: I totally understand you, it's really tough remembering the bits and bytes when it comes to Kubernetes, there are simply too many of them